# Using Openlayers for GeoRSS from remote website

Tags: openlayers-2, georss

I am trying to get features from remote GeoRSS file with Openlayers... But I am stuck. Openlayers can not read remote file. I have searched on the net but I could not find any solution... Here is the code:

```js
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');

var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Osgeo WMS",
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {
    layers: "basic"
});
map.addLayer(wms);

var earthquakes = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("T", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "http://brainoff.com/test/rss.xml",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoRSS()
    }),
});
map.addLayer(earthquakes);

var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([earthquakes]);
map.addControl(select);
select.activate();

var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
    earthquakes, OpenLayers.Handler.Point);
map.addControl(draw);

function toggle() {
    if (document.getElementById("toggle-id").checked) {
        draw.activate();
    } else {
        draw.deactivate();
    }
}
document.getElementById("toggle-id").onclick = toggle;
toggle();
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add details of the problem? Exactly what you meant by "can not read remote file" - what error do you see, what other symptoms, what debugging have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried using a proxy? http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost

Comment: your GeoRSS link does not seem to be a valid GeoRSS.

Comment: I meant that fatures does not appear on the screen. I am new in Openlayers. I have read that i have to build a proxy but i dont know about it.

Comment: #Devdatta Tengshe, you are wrong because when i uploaded that georss data to my host and Openlayers read it succesfully and Qgis opens it. The GeoRSS data is valid !!!                                             #BradHards I meant that features does not appear on the screen. I am new in Openlayers. I have read about using proxy  but i dont know about it.                                            Is there anyway to work with remote located data in Openlayers. Do i have to upload all data to my host...

Comment: @mete7 Have you looked at the link I had posted in my earlier comment about proxy? And I checked your RSS now. It is working fine now. It was throwing an error when I had checked it earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vectors", {
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
                url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
                params: {
                    q: "select * from xml where url='http://brainoff.com/test/rss.xml'"
                },
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoRSS(),
                parseFeatures: function(data) {
                    return this.format.read(data.results[0]);
                }
            }),
            eventListeners: {
                "featuresadded": function () {
                    this.map.zoomToExtent(this.getDataExtent());
                }
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

adaptation of http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cross-origin-xml.html

Comment: People just talk idly but you give the solution. Thanks for your help...